# Dealing with branching tests

Tags: testing

I need to test a multi-step (about 70-90 steps) process that has some specific exit conditions at each step. I have the test for the happy-case path (everything succeeds) and would like to use this as a base for modeling the not-so-happy-case paths (i.e. for each possible exit condition, I need a test case that is a slight variation of the happy-case path).

I've thought about using a variation of the template pattern (i.e. modeling the generic test case driver as the template and basing each individual test off that), but this quickly became quite unwieldy.

Since this is a purely event based systems (communication protocol), I can model the tests as streams of events, but this does not help me in organizing the specific test cases as variations of the generic sequence.

Comment: I think composition might be more useful here: factoring out common testing code infrastructure into consistently grouped function and driving your test cases with the input data while reusing the same testing infrastructure. But you can't get there unless you run through a few cases without thinking of genericity or reuse and then  have look and find out, what is it that make sense to factor out and reuse across the test cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The case you brought in this question looks a lot like a good candidate for data-driven testing strategy. "[xUnit Test Patterns: Refactoring Test Code](http://www.amazon.ca/xUnit-Test-Patterns-Refactoring-Code/dp/0131495054/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1395009312&sr=8-1&keywords=xunit%20test%20patterns%20refactoring%20test%20code)" by *Gerard Meszaros*, defines the conditions for a test to qualify for data-driven testing strategy as follows (p 288):

> For example, we might want to run essentially the same test with
>   slightly different system inputs and verify that the actual output
>   varies accordingly. Each of these tests would consist of exactly the
>   same steps.

Wikipedia entry on [data-driven testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data-driven_testing#Data_Driven) also states:

> Anything that has a potential to change (also called "variability,"
>   and includes elements such as environment, end points, test data,
>   locations, etc.) is separated out from the test logic (scripts) and
>   moved into an 'external asset'. This can be a configuration or test
>   dataset. The logic executed in the script is dictated by the data
>   values.

The recommended **implementation strategy** for data-driven testing is for the **data to be separated from testing logic**. The input and expected output data for each test are stored together in a file or a database and keyed on the test. The testing logic is organized in a modular fashion so as to increase reuse. With the proper implementation language/tools, the testing logic can be grown into a DSL (Domain-Specific-Language) or even a fully-fledged interpreter (recommended in xUnit Test Patterns p288). A consequence of this: the formulation of your tests will be essentially declarative and explicit on the intent and the features being exercised, which will also transform your tests into another meaningful documentation source for your system.

Further reading:

- [Section on data-driven testing in xUnit patterns](http://xunitpatterns.com/Data-Driven%20Test.html) available
  online.
- [Data-driven test automation frameworks](http://safsdev.sourceforge.net/DataDrivenTestAutomationFrameworks.htm#DataDrivenAutomationFrameworks): an article with
  interesting insights on building data-driven test frameworks.

Answer (score 3):

For testing a class's response to variations of a series of events, I've had nice results using [junit-nested](https://github.com/avh4/junit-nested), which let's you nest `setup()` and `teardown()` methods with nested static inner classes:

```
@RunWith(Nested.class)
public class NestedJunitTest {

    @Test public void testWithoutLogin() { // expect 401

    public class LoggedInTests {

        Session session;

        @Before public void login() { session = new Session(..)

        @Test public void testLoggedIn() { ...
```

Similar to [Jasmine's nested describe blocks](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Grouping_Related_Specs_with_%3Ccode%3Edescribe%3C/code%3E).